# Cakephp 3.4 AJAX request throws 403 forbidden error

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, cakephp-3.0, http-status-code-403

I have been trying to send some data to a controller via AJAX but for the life of me I can`t seem to make it work; everytime I make the request, a 403 forbidden error is thrown.

this is the ajax request:

```
$.ajax({
            type: 'post',
            url:"<?php echo Router::url(array('controller'=>'Atls','action'=>'saveTime', '_ext' => 'json'));?>",
            dataType: 'json',
            data: {atl_id: idTimerPaused, time: actual_time},
            beforeSend: function(xhr){

            },
            success: function (response) {

                console.log('Nailed It');

            },
            error: function(jqXHR, exception){
                console.log(jqXHR);
            }
});
return false;
```

the controller action:

```
public function saveTime()
{

    if ($this->request->is('post') && $this->request->is('ajax')) {
        $content = $this->request->getData();

            $query = $this->Atls->query();
            $result = $query
                ->update()
                ->set(
                    $query->newExpr('actual_time = '. $content['time'])
                )
                ->where([
                    'id' => $content['atl_id']
                ])
            ->execute();

        $this->set(compact('content'));
        $this->set('_serialize', ['content']);

        $this->render('ajax_response', 'ajax');
    }
}
```

I have loaded the extensions on the routes.php file (Router::extensions('json', 'xml');)

The request handler is also loaded and the function is allowed:

```
public function initialize()
{
    parent::initialize();
    $this->loadComponent('RequestHandler');
}

public function beforeFilter(Event $event)
{
    parent::beforeFilter($event);
    $this->Auth->allow('saveTime');

    //Change layout for Ajax requests
    $this->viewBuilder()->layout('appTemplate');
    if ($this->request->is('ajax')) {
       $this->viewBuilder()->layout('ajax');
    }
}
```

that "ajax_response" view has also been added.

I can't see where the problem could be. So any help I can get to work this out would be much appreciated.

Comment: hi do you have any .htacess and an URL rewriting enabled on your server?

Comment: @headmax   the .htaccess is the generic one that comes with the framework, It has not been modified. I have mod_rewrite enabled.

Comment: any folder right to limited ?  inferior to 755 in the process call? any error from your  apache or php logs ?

Comment: that's what frustrate me the most, no errors are shown on the logs and all the folders are 755.

Comment: take a look too the rights of the file calling if is 644 :( ?

Comment: are you on linux or windows?

Comment: sadly I`m on a windows machine, I'm starting to think it has something  to do with the problem.

Comment: I just wanted isn't a problem, may be you installed wamp or xamp or something like that? because may be you didn't enabled in the php.ini the error in max scope for developpment and that the reason why you can't show any error very difficult to work like this. You can too enabled extension valgrind is usefull and if you didn't xdebug

Comment: The error log is logging just fine, what I meant is that no error regarding my problem is thrown.

Comment: so you got a apache configuration problem and is in general the  vhosts.conf cos this problem. can i show?

Answer (score 2):

Did you use the 'Csrf'-Component? In my case this was the problem.

https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/controllers/components/csrf.html#csrf-protection-and-ajax-requests

Comment: Great! I'm not sure why this answer doesn't have more points!!

Answer (score 1):

When you got an **403 forbidden** error in most cases the **session is expired** and the user has to login again.

Comment: Why do you think sessions are involved?

Comment: In most of my cases a 403 error was thrown when the session of the user has been expired and an Ajax request was send to a controller were a user needs permission to access the functions.